# Pandas - problem with converting column to int after reading csv

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, utf-8

I am importing csv file that I previously scraped from internet site. 
These are sample lines from this file:

> year,elections,teryt_code,powiat,gmina,political_party,n_votes,percentage
>   2011,sejm,020101,bolesławiecki,Miasto Bolesławiec,Lista nr 1 - Komitet Wyborczy Prawo i Sprawiedliwość - Zarejestrowana,3 496,"22,85"
>   2011,sejm,020101,bolesławiecki,Miasto Bolesławiec,Lista nr 2 - Komitet Wyborczy Polska Jest Najważniejsza - Zarejestrowana,276,"1,80"
>   2011,sejm,020101,bolesławiecki,Miasto Bolesławiec,Lista nr 3 - Komitet Wyborczy Sojusz Lewicy Demokratycznej - Zarejestrowana,1 815,"11,86"
>   2011,sejm,020101,bolesławiecki,Miasto Bolesławiec,Lista nr 4 - Komitet Wyborczy Ruch Palikota - Zarejestrowana,1 867,"12,20"
>   2011,sejm,020101,bolesławiecki,Miasto Bolesławiec,Lista nr 5 - Komitet Wyborczy Polskie Stronnictwo Ludowe - Zarejestrowana,432,"2,82"
>   2011,sejm,020101,bolesławiecki,Miasto Bolesławiec,Lista nr 6 - Komitet Wyborczy Polska Partia Pracy - Sierpień 80 - Zarejestrowana,79,"0,52"
>   2011,sejm,020101,bolesławiecki,Miasto Bolesławiec,Lista nr 7 - Komitet Wyborczy Platforma Obywatelska RP - Zarejestrowana,7 336,"47,94"
>   2011,sejm,020102,bolesławiecki,Gmina Bolesławiec,Lista nr 1 - Komitet Wyborczy Prawo i Sprawiedliwość - Zarejestrowana,1 043,"26,33"
>   2011,sejm,020102,bolesławiecki,Gmina Bolesławiec,Lista nr 2 - Komitet Wyborczy Polska Jest Najważniejsza - Zarejestrowana,68,"1,72"
>   2011,sejm,020102,bolesławiecki,Gmina Bolesławiec,Lista nr 3 - Komitet Wyborczy Sojusz Lewicy Demokratycznej - Zarejestrowana,368,"9,29"

When I import it with line:

```
sejm_df = pandas.read_csv('file.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

And then print it with line:

```
print(sejm_df[0:10].to_string())
```

Lines are printed:

> year elections  teryt_code         powiat               gmina                                    political_party n_votes percentage
>   0  2011      sejm       20101  bolesławiecki  Miasto Bolesławiec  Lista nr 1 - Komitet Wyborczy Prawo i Sprawied...   3 496      22,85
>   1  2011      sejm       20101  bolesławiecki  Miasto Bolesławiec  Lista nr 2 - Komitet Wyborczy Polska Jest Najw...     276       1,80
>   2  2011      sejm       20101  bolesławiecki  Miasto Bolesławiec  Lista nr 3 - Komitet Wyborczy Sojusz Lewicy De...   1 815      11,86
>   3  2011      sejm       20101  bolesławiecki  Miasto Bolesławiec  Lista nr 4 - Komitet Wyborczy Ruch Palikota - ...   1 867      12,20
>   4  2011      sejm       20101  bolesławiecki  Miasto Bolesławiec  Lista nr 5 - Komitet Wyborczy Polskie Stronnic...     432       2,82
>   5  2011      sejm       20101  bolesławiecki  Miasto Bolesławiec  Lista nr 6 - Komitet Wyborczy Polska Partia Pr...      79       0,52
>   6  2011      sejm       20101  bolesławiecki  Miasto Bolesławiec  Lista nr 7 - Komitet Wyborczy Platforma Obywat...   7 336      47,94
>   7  2011      sejm       20102  bolesławiecki   Gmina Bolesławiec  Lista nr 1 - Komitet Wyborczy Prawo i Sprawied...   1 043      26,33
>   8  2011      sejm       20102  bolesławiecki   Gmina Bolesławiec  Lista nr 2 - Komitet Wyborczy Polska Jest Najw...      68       1,72
>   9  2011      sejm       20102  bolesławiecki   Gmina Bolesławiec  Lista nr 3 - Komitet Wyborczy Sojusz Lewicy De...     368       9,29

But I need the column n_votes to be converted to integer. I am trying to do that:

```
sejm_df['n_votes'] = sejm_df['n_votes'].astype('int',True)
```

But only the error appears:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3\xa0496'

Comment: The data you provided does not seem to be formatted well.  There seems to be more columns than header names.  I fixed what you provided the best I could and the data type for column 'n_votes' is  int64 with just df=pd.read_csv('filename.txt', header=0)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you try to convert '3 496' to 3496 which cannot be achieved without processing the no-break space, that is '\xa0'. You can firstly strip the space from that column, such as:

```
df['n_votes'] = df['n_votes'].str.strip()
```

After that you may be able to perform integer converting

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why but strip function didn't work for me.I did the same with: sejm_df['n_votes'] = sejm_df['n_votes'].str.replace('\xa0','')